# Why is this code executing faster than expected?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, execution

I have this code:

```
    public void replay() {
        long previous = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            Thread.Sleep(300);
            long cur = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            Console.WriteLine(cur - previous);
            previous = cur;
        }
    }
```

Which is invoked as a separate thread like this:

```
        MethodInvoker replayer = new MethodInvoker(replay);
        replayer.BeginInvoke(null, null);
```

However, if I watch the output, it acts strangely. It outputs `i` in pairs. For example, it'll wait a full wait, then output `i`, then quickly output the next `i` too, then wait again. Why is it doing that and how can I correct it?

It outputs this:

```
3125040
2968788
2968788
2968788
3125040
2968788
2968788
2968788
3125040
2968788
2968788
2968788
3125040
```

If I increase the sleep to more than a second this doesn't happen.

Comment: First, is this in release or debug mode? Second, use a timer as opposed to just watching the console output - there's no guarantee that the console will display things immediately.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't buffering at the console?

Comment: Looking at the output,  there is less than 5 % variance is the delay between loop executions...   The perceived discrepanacy is just uin the display...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the code to eliminate display latency in your analysis:

```
public void replay() 
{        
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;      
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) 
    {            
          Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Exec:{0} - {1} ms",
                i, DateTime.Now - start));
          start = DateTime.Now;
          Thread.Sleep(300);        
    }
}
```

Looking at your modified output,  there is less than 5% variance (15ms out of the 300)  in the loop delay.  This is normal, due to the uncertainties involved in when the OS actually assigns timeslices to the thread...  (If I recall correctly, in a windows OS, this is normally only every 20 ms !)

The larger discrepancy you perceive in the console output is almost certainly due to display latencys.

Answer (score 5):

Cannot reproduce. I wonder if it is something local to your machine; buffering, perhaps.

Comment: ditto. bring up task manager and watch your processes.  I suspect something's eating up cycles.

Comment: suggest the OP write the output to something else - a Dictionary<Int,DateTime> perhaps - to double check

Comment: updated the question to show more data. I'm on a quad core, and most of the CPU isn't utilized.

Comment: read the question and you'll know. The problem is that it's not sleeping evenly.

Comment: but you're getting just about 300 ms each output, no?

Comment: but I need it to be even, because I'm sleeping to let something render, and then capturing it.

Comment: The difference in sleep times is minimal, and there's no real way to change that.  It looks like it's behaving properly to me.

Comment: Agreed - I don't think there's anything "wrong" here. The "I need it to be even because..." changes the question - I would suggest using a timer or sleep the remaining time (Thread.Sleep(600 - (DateTime.Now.Ticks - previous) / 10000)) to be more accurate...

Comment: Or, you may find the article http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/57/289291.aspx to be of interest.

Comment: There's no way to get it THAT even ( with variance less than the Operating systems context switching interval)

Comment: If you run it with sleep set to, say, 50,000 ms, you will probably see the same ( ~ 15-20 ms) variance... It's just unavoidable - (at least on any OS that implements pre-emptive multi-Processing)

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce this, but you might want to consider a timer.  It would be more reliable.

```
public class Counter
{
    private readonly TimeSpan initialDelay, incrementDelay;
    private readonly int maxCount;
    private Timer timer;
    private int count;

    public Counter(TimeSpan initialDelay, TimeSpan incrementDelay, int maxCount)
    {
        this.maxCount = maxCount;
        this.initialDelay = initialDelay;
        this.incrementDelay = incrementDelay;
    }

    public void Start(Action<int> tickBehavior)
    {
        if (timer != null)
        {
            Timer temp = timer;
            timer = null;
            temp.Dispose();
        }
        timer = new Timer(() =>
            {
                tickBehavior(count++);
                if (count > maxCount) timer.Dispose();
            }, null, initialDelay, incrementDelay);
    }
}
```

Use it:

```
Counter counter = new Counter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.3), 1000);
counter.Start((count) => Console.WriteLine(count););
```

**EDIT**

I'm using `System.Threading.Timer`, but `Counter` could be easily be modified to use `System.Timers.Timer` or `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` depending on your need.  See [this link for a description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) of when to use which timers.

Comment: +1 that piece of code is the coolest thing I've seen all week :)

Answer (score -2):

Your sleep inside the loop is only 300ms, which isn't very long.  You application will do the following:

- Sleep 5 secs
- print 0
- Sleep 300ms
- print 1
- Sleep 300ms
- print 2

etc.

Comment: But it's not, and that's the problem.